# Using google_rest API

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am trying to use the Google Drive API to download publicly available files however whenever I try to proceed I get an import error.

For reference, I have successfully set up the OAuth2 such that I have a client id as well as a client secret , and a redirect url however when I try setting it up I get an error saying the object has no attribute urllen

```
>>> from apiclient.discovery import build
>>> from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
>>> flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id='not_showing_client_id', client_secret='not_showing_secret_id', scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', redirect_uri='https://www.example.com/oauth2callback')
>>> auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
>>> code = '4/E4h7XYQXXbVNMfOqA5QzF-7gGMagHSWm__KIH6GSSU4#'
>>> credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
```

And then I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line     
137, in positional_wrapper
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line    
1980, in step2_exchange
body = urllib.parse.urlencode(post_data)
AttributeError: 'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse' object has no attribute   
'urlencode'
```

Any help would be appreciated, also would someone mind enlightening me as to how I instantiate a drive_file because according to https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads, I need to instantiate one and I am unsure of how to do so.

Edit: So I figured out why I was getting the error I got before. If anyone else is having the same problem then try running.

```
sudo pip install -I google-api-python-client==1.3.2
```

However I am still unclear about the drive instance so any help with that would be appreciated.

Edit 2: Okay so I figured out the answer to my whole question. The drive instance is just the metadata which results when we use the API to search for a file based on its id

Comment: I had a similar problem when trying to connect Google Analytics API. Installing version 1.3.2 of google-api-python-client solved my problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

So as I said in my edits try the sudo pip install and a file instance is just a dictionary of meta data.